# Make traditional output for integrates

Tags: functions, function-construction

I want to perform a traditional output for integrates using a new function that I called `HInt`:

```
HInt[f_, {x_, x1_, x2_}] := Subscript["∫", x1]^x2 "\[DoubleStruckD]" x
```

When I put `HInt[f, {x, 0, 1}]`, I have this output:

[image]

What I have to do to get this output?

[image]

It seems that the integrate symbol is less my symbol and the number one disappear

Comment: You are looking for `Subsuperscript`. But please try to understand the answer linked to your last question. It shows a proper way to define own 2D output notation. Now you have a multiplication of few expressions which will bite you soon.

Comment: Thanks @Kuba...

Comment: Take a look at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zy6-RU6ZAX4

Comment: If you just want the typeset output given in your second example, you could use:  `Integrate[f, {x, 0, 1}] // HoldForm // TraditionalForm`